# What is a brief announcement?

Tags: conference

What is a *brief announcement* in terms of accepted conference papers?

For an example, see [here](http://www.podc.org/podc2011/bas.shtml)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a short conference paper (maybe 2 pages) + a short talk (maybe 5–10 minutes).

Cf. a normal conference paper (maybe 10 pages) + a normal conference talk (maybe 20–25 minutes).

Brief announcements do not usually count as a publication, so you can use them to advertise work published elsewhere, or you can later submit a full version of your work to another conference.

In some conferences, you submit a normal paper, but if it is not quite sufficiently interesting to be accepted as a normal paper, it may be accepted as a brief announcement. In some conferences, brief announcements are a separate track — you directly submit a brief announcement. Some conferences combine both approaches: some of the brief announcements that they accept are "downgraded normal papers", while some of them have been directly submitted as brief announcements.

Comment: In particular, the [conference linked by the OP](http://www.podc.org/podc2011/call_for_papers.shtml) says: "A submission for a brief announcement must be no longer than 3 single-column pages on letter-size paper using at least 11-point font, including title, authors' names and affiliations, and references. Such submissions may describe work in progress or work presented elsewhere. (...) brief announcements will be included in the conference proceedings. (...) brief announcements receive up to 2 letter-size pages."